# How would I implement a multi-type user system for Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, types, rails-activerecord

I'm creating a Rails application where users can sign up by checking a box in a form where they are either a "person" or "organization". I'm struggling to find a way to implement this into Rails. Both of these user types would have the same authorization. I have no idea if I want to use a string or a boolean as a data type in my ActiveRecord database. Also, what would I need to put in my model (User.rb) and my controller in order to validate it and implement it respectively?

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to implement this; it depends on what your needs are.  Ask yourself: "*Do people and organizations share the same attributes?*"

## AR Enum

If they do, the only thing that differentiates the two is role (or whatever you want to call it), i.e., person or organization.  For that scenario, [Rails 4.1 provides AR enums](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html).  This is the simplest solution, it could go something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum role: [ :person, :organization ] # @user.role => 'person', @user.person? => true
end
```

## Polymorphic Association

On the other hand, if people and organizations share only some attributes, you might consider using a [polymorphic association](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations) (If people and organizations share no attributes—not even `role`—they should be two different models).  The base model should contain the attributes that both people and organizations share.  The person/organization models should contain attributes specific to that model.

```
# common attributes
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :profile, polymorphic: true

  def self.roles
    %w(person organization)
  end
end

# person-specific attributes
class PersonProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :profile, dependent: :destroy
end

# organization-specific attributes
class OrganizationProfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, as: :profile, dependent: :destroy
end
```

For user signup, you can create `users#new` and `users#create` actions.  In your user signup form (perhaps `app/views/users/new.html.erb`), you could use a [`select_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-select_tag) to let the user specify their role.  Then, use that to determine what kind of profile to attach to your user model. For example (`users#create`):

```
def create
  @user = User.new(user_params)
  if role = params[:role]
    # return HTTP 400
    head :bad_request and return unless User.roles.include?(role)

    # Assign the User's profile
    @user.profile = "#{role.capitalize}Profile".constantize.new
  else
    # enter your own logic here
  end

  @user.save ? redirect_to(@user) : render(:new)
end
```

The handling of sessions (user signin/signout), in my opinion, should be handled in a separate `SessionsController`.

Comment: Okay thanks @jmera! I think I might implement the polymorphic associations. One major question I have is when a user signs up though, how would I let them choose to be either a "person" or "organization" in the sign up form under the view?

Comment: Hey @jtarr523, see my edits. If I were you, I'd use two different controllers.  One for People, another for Organizations.  It gets messy when you use the same controller for what sounds to me like two fundamentally different models.

Comment: You've got the polymorphic relationship wrong. `PersonProfile` and `OrganizationProfile` always belong to a `User`, so those relationships are not polymorphic. Also, I don't think you can use `has_one` in the way you're intending here -- there's no way for AR to know which table to look in to find the associated record.

Comment: You're right @ToddAgulnick. See my edit. I haven't tested it out, but I'm pretty sure it's right now.

Answer (score 0):

Add a new table to the database named `user_types` with fields `role` and `id`. And in `users` table you need to add `user_type_id` column. Then, in `UserType` model

```
class UserType < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
end
```

And in `User` model you need to add

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user_type
end
```

You can create UserType records in seeds, but make sure it runs everytime the database is reset, add this to `seeds.rb`

```
UserType.create!(role: "person")
UserType.create!(role: "organization")
```

Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two types of users (Person and Organization) as indicated in your question, you could just have a Person model, and add a bool field `is_organization` to it. For more details, See how devise, a popular authentication gem, handles this [here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Add-an-Admin-Role#option-2---adding-an-admin-attribute) (this approach is option 2 on the linked page, you can also check out option 1, which is to create an entire new model).